# Friction. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

I was solving the following question.

> A plank of mass $m_1$ with a bar of mass $m_2$ placed on it lies on a smooth horizontal plane. A horizontal force growing with time $t$ as $F=at$ ($a$ is a constant) is applied to the bar. Find how the accelerations of the plank $w_1$ and of the bar $w_2$ depend on $t$, if the coefficient of friction between the plank and the bar is equal to $k$. Draw the approximate plots of these dependences.

I approached by thinking if the force applied $F$ is to the right and less than the limiting friction $km2g$, then friction will hold the force or completely resist it and the upper block will not move as F will be cancelled by friction as F is less than limiting case of friction.
The lower plank will get the same friction (= F) to the right and move but the upper block will again completely resist it with friction applying to left on the lower block. But this gives rise an infinite chain of friction changing directions and no body moving.
But that is not what happens in real life. Both the blocks move with acceleration F/m1+m2.
THE INFINITE CHAIN I AM TALKING ABOUT--.See let's start from the beginning. Upper block has a force F to the right, there is a friction on upper block to left which causes the lower block to move right (reaction of friction on upper) which causes friction on it by upper block to the left giving again a friction to right by lower on upper.......... the infinite chain of friction changing directions.
What concept am I getting wrong here?

Comment: The question doesn't name the friction between the plane and m1, only talks about a "smooth" plane. Should we interpret that to mean zero friction?

Comment: Yes sir. But that doesnt  clear me.

Comment: That was just a comment, to clarify if I understand the question correctly. I'm preparing an answer.

Comment: There is not a "infinite chain of friction changing directions." There are only two different cases. Either the two masses have the same acceleration, or the top mass has a greater acceleration than the bottom one. It should be obvious (by common sense) that the bottom mass can not accelerate *faster* than the top one.

Comment: alephzero ...See lets start from the beginning. Upper block has a force F to the right, there is a friction on upper block to left which causes the lower block to move right (reaction of friction on upper) which causes friction on it by upper block to the left giving again a friction to right by lower on upper.......... the infinite chain of friction changing directions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given by user Ralf is correct , but I will point the mistake in your argument.

> See lets start from the beginning. Upper block has a force F to the right, there is a friction on upper block to left which causes the lower block to move right (reaction of friction on upper)

Two points to keep in mind :

1. Friction is static here. Unless the value of external force is less than the maximum value of friction , friction will be variable.
2. Friction only prevents relative motion between the two surfaces in contact.  When you are considering the bar you are ignoring this fact and assuming value of external force is equal to the value of static friction , which is wrong. When you assume that the two objects move together , you will find out value of static friction will be less than value of external force on the bar , breaking the infinite chain reaction you are thinking.

Comment: oh god thank you. I get it to some extent.
But see whenever we have a block on floor for example, it will not move if the external applied force is less than limiting static friction as static friction completely equals the external force.
why then in this case the static friction cannot equal the F applied as it is less than the limiting friction.what is stopping it
the lower block not sticking to the ground or what?
pls help

Comment: @chittaranjanrout For the simple reason that the acceleration of the floor is 0. Try to think like this : In order to prevent relative motion btw the two surfaces (which means that the two bodies moves with same acceleration ) ,  the amount of force required is less when the below surface is already accelerating.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the two masses individually makes it difficult to find the friction force between plank and bar.

A different approach is:

- First, model the plank and the bar as a combined system of mass m1+m2, covering the situation that they move together. Compute the acceleration of the combined center of mass.
- Compute the accelerating force needed to make the plank accelerate like that. This force must come from the friction between bar and plank. This situation only applies as long as the force needed is less than the bar-plank maximum friction.
- If/when the force needed exceeds the maximum friction, the plank gets the maximum friction force, and the bar gets two forces, the external force minus the friction force, and you can compute the resulting accelerations for that situation, and you'll have two different accelerations, meaning that the objects start to separate.
- In a real-world scenario, plank and bar will each have limited size, so you'll reach a situation where the bar's center of mass is no longer above the plank, starts to tilt and lose contact with the plank, finally reducing the friction to zero. But I guess that's out of the question's scope.

Comment: See lets start from the beginning. Upper block has a force F to the right, there is a friction on upper block to left which causes the lower block to move right (reaction of friction on upper) which causes friction on it by upper block to the left giving again a friction to right by lower on upper.......... the infinite chain of friction changing directions.